# Do I need to install all modules like server.js ,express.js, andejs in every project directory?

Tags: node.js

im learning nodejs. i dont want to install  modules every time in different project. I mean can use those modules instently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install required packages everytime you create a new project. And after installing once in your project you can use them by `const packageName = require('package-name')`.

In nutshell,

> Packages have to be installed if you want them in your project but installation is done only once.
>
> You should include them in your project using `const packageName = require('package-name')`.
>
> You can save packages in `package.json` file while installing them in your project command is as follows:
>
> `npm install package-name --save`